# Shell script search for a literal dollar sign next to a variable name

Tags: regex, shell, awk, grep, busybox

When searching through code, I'm trying to write a regular expression that needs to search for a literal dollar sign immediately preceding a variable.

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c
$c1
$c2
d
$c-falaffel
$f
```

I want a grep expression that, when passed "c", returns:

```
$c1
$c2
$c-falaffel
```

What I have so far:

```
mode="c"
grep "\\$${mode}" file1
```

But the shell keeps interpreting $$ as asking for the pid.  How in hell do you search an expression that is defined in a variable with a literal dollar sign in front??

Oh, and it has to be good in POSIX-compliant shells (it needs to run on the busybox shell), so bashisms are not acceptable.

Comment: 4 strikes: Never pass the value of shell variables to awk script like that, never enclose awk scripts in double quotes, never use range expressions, and always quote your shell variables. Post some sample input and expected output if you'd like more help.

Comment: @EdMorton 1. Why?  2. Why?  3. Why?  4. Ordinarily I do, but this is known input (no spaces).  I'll refactor the question though so what I'm actually asking for (see: the title) is more clear.

Comment: 1) see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24, 2) because then you need to add escapes before $ signs etc. since $1 for example would then mean the 1st shell positional parameter instead of the first field on the line, 3) because they make trivial solutions VERY slightly briefer but then require a complete re-write for the tiniest change in requirements, and 4) is because leaving variables unquoted is something you should only to do get some specific, necessary behavior from word splitting or globbing it is not something you do just because you think it'd be safe to do so.

Comment: and I do understand the question (see the answer I posted) but we need to fix everything else too or we'll be sticking a band-aid on a broken leg and to come up with a sensible complete solution, we need to see the sample input and expected output.

Comment: I've never seen the awk -v flag before, thanks for calling that to my attention.  And I guess you're right about the other stuff too, I was getting a little sloppy on this one.  There was definitely unnecessary info in the question though, I've chopped it down so just the salient part is still there.

Comment: When you say, `preceding a variable` do you really mean `preceding a symbol`? In your original question it was a variable you were looking for but above it appears to be a symbol but then sometimes you're saving it in a variable before searching for it too. Does the symbol need to be stored in a variable? Please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

you've got one too many backslashes

```
$ mode="c"
$ grep "\$$mode" file1
$c1
$c2
$c-falaffel
$
```

tested in bash 4.2.20, ksh 93u+, and zsh 5.0.5

Answer (score 1):

This might be close to what you need:

```
awk -v RS= -v var="$mode" 'sub(".*if [$]" var "_mode","")' "$0"
```

or maybe this:

```
awk -v RS= -v var="$mode" 'match($0,"if [$]" var "_mode"){print substr($0,RSTART)}' "$0"
```

Once you post some input and output we'll have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to Ed Morton's answer: you have to build the string.

```
search_string='$'
search_string="${search_string}$mode"
grep "$search_string" file1
```

Comment: While this works, it's more complicated than it needs to be - just use "\$$mode" (see @AaronDavies' answer).

Comment: Absolutely not. I was passing a shell variable value into an awk script and there constructing a string based on your previous question. Your current question is very different and has a much simpler answer (see @AaronDavies answer).